# twisted autobahn websocket being initialized twice with wss

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I have some websocket protocols implemented with Twisted, they work fine when I connect using "ws", but when I enable secure websockets, the `__init__` method is called twice. To more specific, it is called once, then the connection apparently fails, with connectionLost being called, then it the `__init__` is called again, and this time the connection stays open.

The code bellow exemplifies it. When I connect with wss, the log line in the `__init__` of the websocket protocol is called twice, but this doesn't happen with plain websockets.

import socket
    from datetime import datetime
    from twisted.internet import reactor

```
from twisted.internet.ssl import DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory

from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServerFactory, listenWS
import txaio

txaio.use_twisted()


CERT_KEY = "certificate.key"
CERT_PATH = "certificate.crt"


def log(msg):
    print("{}: {}".format(str(datetime.now()), msg))


class TestProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestProtocol, self).__init__()
        log("Test protocol init")

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        WebSocketServerProtocol.connectionLost(self, reason)
        log("Connection closed: Reason is {}".format(reason))


class TestProtocolFactory(WebSocketServerFactory):
    protocol = TestProtocol


def init_websocket_protocol(factory_cls, port):
    try:
        key, crt = CERT_KEY, CERT_PATH
        context_factory = DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory(key, crt)
        connection_string = "wss://localhost:{}".format(str(port))
        factory = factory_cls(connection_string)
        listenWS(factory, contextFactory=context_factory)
        log("Port {} bound to test websocket server".format(str(port)))
    except socket.error as e:
        log("Server was unable to bind to a new port: ".format(str(e)))


def main():
    init_websocket_protocol(TestProtocolFactory, 9000)
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The recommend API these days is to use endpoints. Also, `twisted.internet.ssl.CertificateOptions` is the preferred API for TLS connections. So with those changes your code above would look like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, WebSocketServerFactory
from twisted.internet.ssl import CertificateOptions, PrivateCertificate, Certificate, KeyPair
from twisted.internet.endpoints import SSL4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.internet.task import react
from OpenSSL import crypto


CERT_KEY = "certificate.key"
CERT_PATH = "certificate.crt"


def log(msg):
    print("{}: {}".format(str(datetime.now()), msg))


class TestProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestProtocol, self).__init__()
        log("Test protocol init")

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        WebSocketServerProtocol.connectionLost(self, reason)
        log("Connection closed: Reason is {}".format(reason))



class TestProtocolFactory(WebSocketServerFactory):
    protocol = TestProtocol


def init_websocket_protocol(reactor, port):
    with open(CERT_KEY) as key_file, open(CERT_PATH) as cert_file:
        key = KeyPair.load(key_file.read(), crypto.FILETYPE_PEM).original
        cert = Certificate.loadPEM(cert_file.read()).original
    ctx = CertificateOptions(
        privateKey=key,
        certificate=cert,
    )
    return SSL4ServerEndpoint(reactor, port, ctx)


def main(reactor):
    ep = init_websocket_protocol(reactor, 9000)
    ep.listen(TestProtocolFactory())
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    react(main)
```

When I run this code and point Firefox at it, it connects once. What does the browser-side code you're using look like?

Comment: I'm creating a new websocket with `var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:9000");`. I ran this, but I still having the same problem, it initializes the protocol object, than closes the connection, than initializes it again, but this time stays open.


I'm adding a https endpoint so I can accept the certificate, but I even restarted the server without the https endpoint, to see if it would make a difference, but it didn't.


Also tried with firefox, didn't let me connect at all with this code either.

Comment: This is a self-signed certificate or similar? Can you try using this code to create your certificates? https://github.com/crossbario/crossbarexamples/tree/master/authentication/tls/static

Comment: I know this is coming reaaaaally late, but, I just tried using the create-self-signed-cert.sh to create the certificate and I'm still getting the same bug. Back in 2016 (Jesus, it's been literally years) I just add a bunch of hasattr checks to avoid errors with the open/close/open again thing, but now we changed a bunch of stuff and that's not doable anymore =/